# doctrine orm:schema-tool:create - Class Bug does not exist

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

Hi this is my first time doing doctrin22 but i cant get it to work,

here is my code

index.php

```php
<?php
if (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')) {
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));
} else {
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'production');
}

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine');
$classLoader->register();

$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration(); // (2)

// Proxy Configuration (3)
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__.'/lib/MyProject/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('MyProject\Proxies');
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses((APPLICATION_ENV == "development"));

// Mapping Configuration (4)
$driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(__DIR__."/config/mappings/xml");
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);


// Caching Configuration (5)
if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
} else {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
}
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

// database configuration parameters (6)
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager (7)
$evm = new Doctrine\Common\EventManager();
$entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config, $evm);
?>
```

cli-config.php

```php
<?php
require_once 'index.php';
$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($entityManager)
));
?>
```

and my folder structure

```
myproject/index.php
myproject/cli-config.php
myproject/config/mappings/xml/Bug.dcm.xml
myproject/config/mappings/xml/Product.dcm.xml
myproject/config/mappings/xml/User.dcm.xml
```

when i run 
    myproject/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql

i get the following

```
doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
PHP Warning:  class_parents(): Class Bug does not exist and could not be loaded in /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php:50
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:39
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
PHP   7. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:53
PHP   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:131
PHP  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:178
PHP  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:254
PHP  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:231
PHP  13. class_parents() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:40

Warning: class_parents(): Class Bug does not exist and could not be loaded in /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40

Call Stack:
    0.0001     625400   1. {main}() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:0
    0.0002     639440   2. include('/usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php') /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:4
    0.0086    4245576   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php:50
    0.0151    6311808   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:39
    0.0164    6761376   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
    0.0169    6761544   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
    0.0171    6761920   7. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
    0.0171    6761920   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:53
    0.0172    6764016   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:131
    0.0172    6764064  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:178
    0.0172    6764280  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:254
    0.0173    6799712  12. Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:231
    0.0173    6799760  13. class_parents() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:40

PHP Warning:  array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 231
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php:50
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:39
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
PHP   7. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:53
PHP   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:131
PHP  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:178
PHP  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:254
PHP  12. array_reverse() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:231

Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 231

Call Stack:
    0.0001     625400   1. {main}() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:0
    0.0002     639440   2. include('/usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php') /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:4
    0.0086    4245576   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php:50
    0.0151    6311808   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:39
    0.0164    6761376   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
    0.0169    6761544   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
    0.0171    6761920   7. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
    0.0171    6761920   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:53
    0.0172    6764016   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:131
    0.0172    6764064  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:178
    0.0172    6764280  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:254
    0.0176    6799840  12. array_reverse() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:231

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 231
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:0
PHP   2. include() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:4
PHP   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php:50
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:39
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
PHP   7. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
PHP   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:53
PHP   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:131
PHP  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:178
PHP  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:254

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 231

Call Stack:
    0.0001     625400   1. {main}() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:0
    0.0002     639440   2. include('/usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php') /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine:4
    0.0086    4245576   3. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() /usr/local/zend/bin/doctrine.php:50
    0.0151    6311808   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:39
    0.0164    6761376   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
    0.0169    6761544   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:194
    0.0171    6761920   7. Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\AbstractCommand->execute() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:224
    0.0171    6761920   8. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/SchemaTool/AbstractCommand.php:53
    0.0172    6764016   9. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:131
    0.0172    6764064  10. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:178
    0.0172    6764280  11. Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getParentClasses() /usr/local/zend/share/pear/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:254




[ReflectionException]     
Class Bug does not exist  



orm:schema-tool:create [--dump-sql]
```

Comment: Did you wrote your entities classes?

Comment: Can you post the content of this file: myproject/config/mappings/xml/Bug.dcm.xml

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your Bug.dcm.xml file I can't see if you declared your class right. But looking at your xml file name you forgot to add a namespace to your Bug class. If you give your Bug class the namespace Foo your filename should be Foo.Bug.dcm.xml.

One other thing you need to do is adding the choosen namespace to your doctrine classloader. Just like you did with the Doctrine namespace. I case you use the namespace Foo it will look like this:

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Foo', <<PATH_TO_FOO>>);
$classLoader->register();
```

Replace <> to the path where your namespace starts.

If this does not fix your problem post your Bug.dcm.xml.